# Semaphores in a single thread

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, single-threaded

I was wondering whether it would ever make sense to use a mutex or semaphore when there is only one thread?.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I design thread protection into my components because they are reusable and scalable components intended to work in any environment I can realistically anticipate.  Many times they are initially used in a single thread environment.  Often times the scope of the implementation expands to include more threads.  Then I don't have to chase down resources to protect from the new access scenarios.

Comment: Yep, it is always a good idea to think ahead with regards to concurrency.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am facing. At the moment my program is single-threaded, but it is highly likely that there will be multiple threads in the future ...

Answer (score 1):

Mutex can make sense, since Mutex can be used for system wide sharing, instead of internal process-wide sharing.  For example, you can use a Mutex to [prevent an application from being started twice](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit out there but lets say you are writing a recursive function and you want each level to register with a separate resource. This way you can keep the responsibility of cleaning up the resource in one place *(The resource pool)*.

Comment: In a truly single threaded app, though, there's probably better options for this...

Comment: @Reed - I am sure of it, that's why I added my little disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a trick question.  Technically, yes.  A named mutex can be used to synch multiple processes containing a single thread in each.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system-wide semaphores` (and even mutexes) to do `inter-process communication`.

You can signal from a single-threaded process to another single-threaded process by `acquire()/release()`-ing on a named semaphore, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case the environment supports system interrupts it adds non-linear behaviour.
Semaphore can be used in order to sleep in main thread until interrupt triggers.